# How to create your own global breakpoint plugin (called mobile) in Nuxt js with Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to create my own breakpoint in Nuxt/vuetify project so i can manage it from one place and i can call it instant of $vuetif.breakpoint..... etc

For this , i created one plugin file (mobile.js). It works very well . But problem, it is slower than a normal breakpoint .

For example ,

```
<span v-if="mobile"><show</span>
<span v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown"><show</span>
```

Both work but first line (mobile plugin) works slower . I want my plugin working faster .

My plugin (mobile.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const mobilex = {
  data() {
    return {
      mobile: false,
    }
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize, { passive: true })
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.onResize()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize, { passive: true })
  },
  methods: {
    onResize() {
      this.mobile = window.innerWidth < 960
    },
  },
}

Vue.mixin(mobilex)
```

in nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [  '~/plugins/mobile' ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to work, it needs to be executed on client-side as window is not defined on server-side, this is why it takes some time.

If you want something faster, you can use a mobile detection package such as [@nuxtjs/device](https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module) or check the User agent.